# ValueListenableBuilder is not rebuilding the screen, when hotreloading, it is working

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a note app, all data and other things is working perfectly, cos the data is displaying to the screen when the code file is saving, its weird , first time facing this problem

in short, the valuelistanble is not listening when the data adding from app, but when just hot reloading the data is displaying

how can i fix this,
here is the code

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      final value = await NoteDB.instance.getAllNotes();
    });

           ____________________________________________
           ____________________________________________
           //code line for aligment 

            Expanded(
                child: ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: NoteDB.instance.noteListNotifier,
              builder: (context, List<NoteModel> newNotes, _) {
                return GridView.count(
                  childAspectRatio: 3 / 4,
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 34,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 30,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  //generating list for all note
                  children: List.generate(
                    newNotes.length,
                    (index) {
                      //setting the notelist to a variable called [note]
                      final note = newNotes[index];
                      if (note.id == null) {
                        //if the note's id is null set to sizedbox
                        //the note id never be null
                        const SizedBox();
                      }
                      return NoteItem(
                        id: note.id!,
                        //the ?? is the statement (if null)
                        content: note.content ?? 'No Content',
                        title: note.title ?? 'No Title',
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            )),
```

here is the NoteDB.instance.getAllNotes(); function

```
       @override
  Future<List<NoteModel>> getAllNotes() async {
  

    final _result = await dio.get(url.baseUrl+url.getAllNotes);
    if (_result.data != null) {
      final  noteResponse = GetAllNotes.fromJson(_result.data);
      noteListNotifier.value.clear();
      noteListNotifier.value.addAll(noteResponse.data.reversed);
      noteListNotifier.notifyListeners();
      return noteResponse.data;
    } else {
      noteListNotifier.value.clear();
      return [];
    }

  }
```

and also there is a page to create note , and when create note button pressed there is only one function calling here is function

```
Future<void> saveNote() async {
    final title = titleController.text;
    final content = contentController.text;
    final _newNote = NoteModel.create(
      id: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
      title: title,
      content: content,
    );
    final newNote = await NoteDB().createNote(_newNote);
    if (newNote != null) {
      print('Data Added to the DataBase Succesfully!');
      Navigator.of(scaffoldKey.currentContext!).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => HomePage()),
              (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    } else {
      print('Error caught while data adding to the DataBase');
    }
  }
```

everything work fine, but while add the data the UI isn't refreshing even tho notifier is active

and if you need full code please have a look at this github link : https://github.com/Mishalhaneef/Note-app

Comment: did you make sure to call `notifyListeners` inside your notifier ?

Comment: yes i did call that, but still not working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this `ValueNotifier` has a type of `List<NoteModel>`, the value will not change when you add new items to the list or delete from it or clear all. The value here is a reference to the list which does not change.

You have to assign a new value to it, like:

```
noteListNotifier.value = List<NoteModel>[<add your current items here>];
```

You can manipulate your current list with `List.from`, `removeWhere`, `add` etc., and then re-assign the complete list.

Besides you don't need to call `notifyListeners` in case of a `ValueNotifier`, the framework handles it, see [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/7e9793dee1/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart#L412).

Another approach would be to use a custom `ChangeNotifierProvider` where you can call `notifyListeners` when the contents of your list are changed.

Some further suggestions:

1. In your `homescreen.dart` file, instead of `NoteDB.instance.noteListNotifier.value[index]` you can use `newNotes[index]`.
2. In `data.dart`, within `getAllNotes`, you have to set a new value for `noteListNotifier` in order to get the changes propagated. Currently you are just modifying items in this list and that is not considered to be a change. Try this code:

```
  @override
  Future<List<NoteModel>> getAllNotes() async {
    //patching all data from local server using the url from [Post Man]
    final _result = await dio.get(url.baseUrl+url.getAllNotes);
    if (_result.data != null) {
      //if the result data is not null the rest operation will be operate
      //recived data's data decoding to json map
      final _resultAsJsonMap = jsonDecode(_result.data);
      //and that map converting to dart class and storing to another variable
      final getNoteResponse = GetAllNotes.fromJson(_resultAsJsonMap);
      noteListNotifier.value = getNoteResponse.data.reversed;
      //and returning the class
      return getNoteResponse.data;
    } else {
      noteListNotifier.value = <NoteModel>[];
      return [];
    }
  }
```

Comment: its not working or I just missunderstood how the code work you given, now i just did that [pushAndRemoveUntil] navigator for to get add page also when press add note button, cos it will reload the homepage again, now it is working, i don't know what the actual prblem still, if you could explain a little bit that would be a lot help for me, also i appreciate your time sir

Comment: Please update you question with all related code and I will have a look at it. Basically either you set a new value (a list) for the `ValueNotifier` instead of changing only the items of the list, or you create a `ChangeNotifierProvider` to take care of it.

Comment: i updated the whole code that you needed to check also i added a link for to get the full code, also here's the full code link : https://github.com/Mishalhaneef/Note-app,  . and really big thanks for your valuable time sir

Comment: I added to my answer, please check.